# Is it possible to get code-hinting in JetBrains WebStorm for a non-core node package?

Tags: configuration, webstorm, buster.js

Is it possible to get code-hinting in JetBrains WebStorm for a non-core node package?  Specifically, I'd like to get hinting/completion working for buster. I can't seem to find any information on this. Thanks much!

Comment: Try http://devnet.jetbrains.com/thread/435204

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For buster.js, download [buster-test.js](http://docs.busterjs.org/en/latest/download/) and save it somewhere the WebStorm/PyCharm project can see it.  Hinting should show up immediately.

Answer (score 0):

WebStorm 2020.1

There's a trick to getting "coding assistance" for 3rd party packages that support community stubs (AKA Typescript definition files):

1. Open the project's package.json
2. Position the cursor on the package (within the dependencies section)
3. Press alt+enter (or click the light bulb)
4. Choose Install '@types/**name**' (where **name** is the dependency)

For example:

[image]