# WebStorm intellisense node packages

Tags: node.js, intellisense, webstorm, javascript-intellisense

I have npm installed two packages (q, async).
For the first one, the intellisense works great, for the second it's not.

Do you have any idea what can I do to have the intellisense work for any node package like it works for the Q package?

Thanks!

[image: Q]

[image: async]

Comment: It makes no sense to install both Q and async, their use cases overlap. Not to mention that both are rather ancient packages. The intellisense is determined by a .d.ts file.

Comment: Thanks... but it's just for educational purposes.
What .d.ts has to do with javascript btw? isn't it part of typescript?

Comment: It's a typescript definitions file - typescript uses the definitelytyped repository to find type definitions to give you intellisense (in JavaScript)

Comment: TypeScript definitions can also be added via package.json, see:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/62440689/8413913

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get better coding assistance for some modules it is recommended to add TypeScript definition files as WebStorm JavaScript libraries. Go to Preferences | Languages and Frameworks | JavaScript | Libraries - click Download..., search for async - click Download and Install.
You can learn a bit more about WebStorm code completion here: http://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2014/07/how-webstorm-works-completion-for-javascript-libraries/